# Rails - Serialize Model to JSON with camelize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, serialization, activerecord

I need to serialize a model to json and have all of the keys be camelized.  I see that there's an option in to_xml to allow camel case.  I can't seem to coerce the json serialization into giving me back a camelized hash.  Is this something that's possible in rails?

Comment: Based on Bert's recommendation we went with RABL.  Couldn't be happier, here's a tutorial to get rolling with RABL: http://blog.dcxn.com/2011/06/22/rails-json-templates-through-rabl/

Comment: how did you get rabl to return camelized json?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems weird to me to use camelized attribute names in Rails, let alone json. I would stick to the conventions and use underscored variable names.

However, have a look at this gem: [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). It should be able to help you out.

Comment: Bert- you're on the ball.  Thanks for looking at this question as well.  I'm trying to get the rails json api to be as clean as possible for the javascript dev on the other end.  RABL looks like it could save me a ton of time!  Thanks!

Comment: javascript uses camelcase by convention, would it not make more sense for json attributes to camelized as well?

Comment: Tip: if you're using something like [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) that doesn't like the [json-api](http://jsonapi.org/) style responses from RABL, try using `object @thing => false` for objects and `:object_root => false` on child and collections

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue. After a bit of research I wrapped the [as_json](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fe49f432c9a88256de753a3f2263553677bd7136/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb#L88) ActiveModel method with a helper that would camelize Hash keys. Then I would include the module in the relevant model(s):

```
# lib/camel_json.rb
module CamelJson
  def as_json(options)
    camelize_keys(super(options))
  end

  private
  def camelize_keys(hash)
    values = hash.map do |key, value|
      [key.camelize(:lower), value]
    end
    Hash[values]
  end
end



# app/models/post.rb
require 'camel_json'
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    include CamelJson
end
```

This worked really well for our situation, which was relatively simplistic. However if you're using JBuilder, apparently there's a configuration to set camel case as the default: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23803997/251500

Comment: For purely scientific reasons, I used this code, but had to modify it to check that the key and value are not nil. Put it in `values = hash.map do |key, value|` Minor change, just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Note that this implementation will not convert keys of nested hashes. For instance, `user.as_json(only: [:first_name], include: :mailing_address)` will leave `zip_code` snake-cased: `{"firstName" => "Alan", "mailingAddress" => {"id": 1, "zip_code" => "10004"}`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using rails, skip the added dependency and use `Hash#deep_transform_keys`. It has the added benefit of also camelizing *nested* *keys* (handy if you are doing something like `user.as_json(includes: :my_associated_model)`):

```
h = {"first_name" => "Rob", "mailing_address" => {"zip_code" => "10004"}}
h.deep_transform_keys { |k| k.camelize(:lower) }
=> {"firstName"=>"Rob", "mailingAddress"=>{"zipCode"=>"10004"}}
```

Source: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb#L88

Answer (score 1):

For my case,I was required to customize some key names.

**Usage**

```
puts self.camelize_array(array:Post.all.to_a,conditions:{id: "_id",post_type: "type"})
```

**Implementation**

```
def self.camelize_array(array:,conditions: {})
    final = JSON.parse array.to_json
    final.each do |a|
        a.transform_keys! do |key| 
            if conditions.keys.include? key.to_sym
                key = conditions[key.to_sym]
            else
                key.camelize(:lower)
            end
        end
    end
    final.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with RABL Renderer directly, you can pass an inline template, instead of fetching it from a file:

```
Rabl::Renderer.new("\nattributes :name, :description", object).render
```

The `\n` character is necessary at the beginning of the string.