# Rails render json object with camelCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api

I have the following controller code in a simple Rails API:

```
class Api::V1::AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render json: Account.all
  end

  def show
    begin
      render json: Account.includes(:cash_flows).find(params[:id]), include: :cash_flows
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
      head :not_found
    end
  end
end
```

The problem with this is that, the generated json have the format:

```
{
  id:2,
  name: 'Simple account',
  cash_flows: [
    {
      id: 1,
      amount: 34.3,
      description: 'simple description'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      amount: 1.12,
      description: 'other description'
    }
  ]
}
```

**I need that my generated json is camelCase**('cashFlows' instead of 'cash_flows')

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should consider starting with JBuilder. I would highly recommend you to start using it and leverage its functionality. It will allows you play more with your responses and do more detail mappping. You can start here: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder or here http://richonrails.com/articles/getting-started-with-jbuilder#.U30dUiis_1E

Answer (score 11):

Following the recommended by [@TomHert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1290852/tom-hert), I used [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) and the available config:

> Keys can be auto formatted using key_format!, this can be used to convert keynames from the standard ruby_format to camelCase:

```
json.key_format! camelize: :lower
json.first_name 'David'

# => { "firstName": "David" }
```

> You can set this globally with the class method key_format (from inside your environment.rb for example):

```
Jbuilder.key_format camelize: :lower
```

Thanks!!!